# calling IntentService.startService() very often

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I would like to ask if there is something like intent overflow when

```
WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork()
```

or in general

```
IntentService.startService()
```

is called very often not waiting for previous jobs to be finished. I am thinking of a situation that due to user's input it might happen that the job takes 1 minute but it is called every 10 seconds. Should I implement any mechanism to protect from starting too many jobs? Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I implement any mechanism to protect from starting too many jobs?

If you anticipate frequent stretches where your added jobs exceed the processed jobs, you should consider doing *something* to help manage that. While I am not aware of a hard exception before `OutOfMemoryError` -- which, unless you have some pretty big `Intent` extras, is rather unlikely here -- your `IntentService` will just keep running and running and running. Along the way, it will be chewing up CPU, RAM, possibly bandwidth (depending on what the work is), and hence battery life.